# Rails collection and partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a stupid and rapid question:

I'm calling a partial from a view:

```
= render partial: "event_contents", collection: @event.event_contents
```

Inside my '_event_contents.html.haml' view I must use 'event_contents' to refear to any object of the collection. If I use 'event_content' it doesn't work. Why plural?

Comment: @lurker event_contents inside my view is a single object! 

I don't have to loop insiede the collection to create my list of event_contents.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The variable naming the object inside the partial is named after the partial in this case, which you have plural. If your partial is called `_event_content.html.erb` then the variable will be singular. See [Rails Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).